# How to access the form inside dxTemplate inside Devextreme dxPopover in Angular2

Tags: angular, devextreme

I need to subscribe to changes in a form that is inside a dxPopover as below, but the form is always undefined.

However, if I move the form outside of dxPopover, then there is no issues.

How to access the form element when it's inside the dxPopover?

Template:

```
<dx-popover 
                target="#button" 
                position="bottom"
                width="900px" 
                [visible]="true">

    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
            <form  #form="ngForm" >
                <!-- form content -->
            </form>
    </div>
</dx-popover>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('form') form;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.form); // outputs 'undefined'

}
```

edit: Here is a plunk - https://plnkr.co/edit/nQJ0brGs0FlMBkexuavK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the contents of the dxPopover doesn't even exist in the DOM when the popover is hidden, it's not possible to do a `@ViewChild` on it.

However, accessing both forms is possible when the popover is shown.

[Here is the updated plunk.](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/EyLuJLRY02yLp5J1?preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

passing the HTML like you did inside the dxPopover tag requires you to add `<ng-content>` inside the template of dxPopover so it gets injected and then after the view init lifecycle hook you could be accessing the variable in question.

**Option 2:**

you should be moving that `div` inside your `dx-popover` component directive inside the actual component template.

then use the output decorator to emit the value of the form to the parent component which is hosting the `dx-popover` component

and if you want to pass data to the `dx-popover` component you can use the Input decorator as the other way around.

please check the official docs for an example [Here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why I would want to use Input / Output for this simple task. I added a plunk. If you have a moment, please modify. Thanks!